# Can lmer() use splines as random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, splines

Say we're working on a random effects model of some count data over time, and we want to control for some trends. Normally, you'd do something like:

```
lmer(counts ~ dependent_variable + (1+t+I(t^2)|ID), family="poisson")
```

to include a quadratic shape for `t`. Is it possible to use some more sophisticated smoothing techniques like a LOESS smoother or splines to model that relationship?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If what you show works for a `lmer` formula for a random effects term then you should be able to use functions from the **splines** package that comes with R to set up the relevant basis functions.

```
require("lme4")
require("splines")
lmer(counts ~ dependent_variable + (bs(t) | ID), family="poisson")
```

Depending on what you want to do, you should also look at the **gamm4** package and the **mgcv** package. The former is essentially formalising the `bs()` bit in the `lmer()` call above and allows smoothness selection to be performed as part of the analysis. The latter with function `gam()` allows for some degree of flexibility in fitting models like this (if I understand what you are trying to do). It looks like you want separate trends within `ID`? A more fixed effects approach would be something like:

```
gam(counts ~ dependent_variable + ID + s(t, by = ID) , family="poisson")
```

Random effects can be included in `gam()` models using the `s(foo, bs = "re")` type terms where `foo` would be `ID` in your example. Whether it makes sense to combine the `by` term idea with a random effect is something to think about and not something I am qualified to comment on.

Comment: But note that the call to `bs`  needs to be changed to `bs(t, df=4)`  say, because the naked call `bs(t)` just has the same effect as `t`