# One population, two variables, two timepoints: the proper statistical method?

Tags: r, mixed-model, structural-equation-modeling

I have a group of subjects (n = 29), and they've been tested for two variables at baseline and after 1 year. For the argument, let's assume these two as var_behavior and var_brain. Hypothetically, and based on other studies, var_behavior ~ var_brain is an inverted U-shape relationship. Of note, age and gender of my subjects are covariates. My questions are what statistical method can I use to test:

1. if the changes in one is associated with changes in the other
2. if Q#1 = true, does it fit the inverted U model?

I was trying to fit a bivariate latent change score model using Lavaan in R, but due to the low subject count, it was not a good fit. I was also thinking of a linear mixed-effect model, so I converted to a long format with subjectID, var_behavior, var_brain, and visit (baseline or year one), assigning each subject two rows for two visit values. The formula was:

```r
var_behavior ~ var_brain + (1|visit) + (1|subjectID) + Age + Gender
```

But I'm not sure whether it is an optimal choice.

Comment: Spline functions (doable in lme4) and/or generalized additive models (GAM) would be a fruitful area for you to investigate. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36345/can-lmer-use-splines-as-random-effects https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2021/02/02/random-effects-in-gams/